# Visual Studio Winforms Designer Blue Arrow

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

What do the blue arrows located on the top left of a control indicate when they are present in Visual Studio 2010/C#? For example:

[image]

Comment: I have seen them in Web projects, are you sure with that winform tag of yours ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the controls inherited from the window/control the current window/control is inheriting from.

These controls are in the parent window.